# Evaluating an complex integral

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z) = \frac{1}{(1-z)^3} $. Evaluate $\int_{|z-1|= \frac{1}{2}} f(z) dz $

We know $|z-1|=\frac{1}{2}$ is parametrized by the curve $\gamma(t) = \frac{1}{2}e^{it} + 1 $ where $t \in [0,2 \pi]$. We know $f(z)$ is analytic on the inside on this curve. We show $\gamma$ is homotopic to a point that lies this curve. Let $H(s,t) = \frac{s}{2}e^{it} + 1 $. Notice $H(0,t) = 1$. $H(1,t) = \gamma(t)$ and $H(s,0) = H(s,2 \pi)$. Therefore, $\gamma$ is homotopic to the point $z=1$. It follows by Homotopic version of Cauchys theorem that

$$ \int_{|z-1|= \frac{1}{2} } f(z) dz = 0 $$

is this a correct approach ?

Comment: The problem is that $f$ is *not* analytic in the region inside $\gamma$. Are you familiar with the Cauchy Integral formula?

Comment: The only thing that strikes me as off is that $f(z)$ is not analytic everywhere inside the curve. It's analytic inside $\gamma$ where $z \ne1$.

Comment: Also, I agree with Alex that Cauchy's Integral Formula is the more efficient approach, but understanding the deformation of contours is the key to applying CIF anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid that you have to do it directly.
Let $\gamma(t) = \frac{1}{2}e^{it}+1$ where $t \in [0, 2 \pi]$.
$$\int_\gamma \frac{1}{(1-z)^3}dz = \int_0^{2 \pi}\frac{8}{-e^{3it}}(\frac{i}{2}e^{it}) = 4i \int_0^{2\pi}e^{-2it}dt = -2e^{-2it}|_0^{2\pi}= 0$$